# React Native capture video using camera as abackground service in app

Tags: react-native, android-camera

I need to know if there is a way to capture the video recording using front camera of the phone while using an application. Camera should not be opened in the application UI.

Framework - React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the camera, but hiding the `<View>` and `<RNCamera>`.

I made this code to achieve it:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

export default class App extends Component {
  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);

      console.log(data.uri); // log picture encoded in base64 data format.
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.takePicture(), 500); // delay while camera is loading, then take picture.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          style={styles.camera}
          ref={ref => { this.camera = ref; }}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 1,
    width: 1,
    opacity: 0,
  },
  camera: {
    height: 1,
    width: 1,
    opacity: 0,
  },
});
```